# How to get paykey using Paypal Adeptive and make successful checkout in checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

i am using paypal adaptive parallel payments using light box so that user resides on my own site without redirections.

I am simply want when i click on payment button i will get dynamic key in the form and so on the posting form lightbox opens up and i gets payment from sender and split the money in 2 accounts.

```
paypal business account: 
mohsin@balianti.com that is my site admin account as well. who will receive 10% from total amount.

sanbox account that i created in mohsin@balianti.com sandbox account options: mmskit@outlook.com that will receive 90% of total money.

so mohsin@balianti.com as a site admin and holding business account will receive 10% while other receiver will receive 90%.
means total money will split in both accounts.
```

hope you will got my point.

the problem is that:

```
1- i am not getting paykey from paypal.
2- i am unable to do the transaction in light box.
3- i am unable to slipt the money in 2 receivers and so unable to complete to process.
```

My HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=AP-5S482348KH512131U-->
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=NOT KNOW HOW TO GET THIS PAY KEY ON THE BUTTON CLICK" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
<label for="buy">Buy Now:</label>
<input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

My Config.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Timezone Setting
 * List of Supported Timezones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
 */
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

/**
  * Enable Sessions
  * Checks to see if a session_id exists.  If not, a new session is started.
  */
if(!session_id()) session_start();

/** 
 * Sandbox Mode - TRUE/FALSE
 * Check the domain of the current page and set $sandbox accordingly.
 * This allows you to automatically use Sandbox or Live credentials throughout 
 * your application based on what server the app is running from.
 * 
 * I like to do this so I don't forget to update Sandbox credentials to Live
 * prior to uploading files to a production server.
 * 
 * In this case, it's checking to see if the current URL is http://sandbox.domain.*
 * If so, $sandbox is true and the PayPal sandbox will be used throughout.  If not, 
 * we'll assume it must be a live transaction and will use live credentials throughout.
 *
 * Following this pattern will allow you to create your own http://sandbox.domain.com test server, 
 * and then any time your code runs from that server, PayPal's sandbox will be used automatically.
 * 
 * If you would rather just set $sandbox to true/false on your own that's fine, 
 * but you have to make sure your live server always uses false and your test server
 * always uses true.  It's easy to forget this and up with real customers processing 
 * payments from your live site on the PayPal sandbox.
 */
$host_split = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$sandbox = $host_split[0] == 'sandbox' && $host_split[1] == 'domain' ? TRUE : FALSE;
$domain = $sandbox ? 'http://sandbox.domain.com/' : 'http://lahori.org/mydev/themusicnetwork/';

/**
 * Enable error reporting if running in sandbox mode.
 */
if($sandbox)
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
}

/* 
 * PayPal API Version
 * ------------------
 * The library is currently using PayPal API version 109.0.  
 * You may adjust this value here and then pass it into the PayPal object when you create it within your scripts to override if necessary.
 */
$api_version = '109.0';

/*
 * PayPal Application ID
 * --------------------------------------
 * The application is only required with Adaptive Payments applications.
 * You obtain your application ID but submitting it for approval within your 
 * developer account at http://developer.paypal.com
 *
 * We're using shorthand if/else statements here to set both Sandbox and Production values.
 * Your sandbox values go on the left and your live values go on the right.
 * The sandbox value included here is a global value provided for developrs to use in the PayPal sandbox.
 */
$application_id = $sandbox ? 'APP-80W284485P519543T' : '';

/*
 * PayPal Developer Account Email Address
 * This is the email address that you use to sign in to http://developer.paypal.com
 */
$developer_account_email = 'mohsin@balianti.com';

/*
 * PayPal Gateway API Credentials
 * ------------------------------
 * These are your PayPal API credentials for working with the PayPal gateway directly.
 * These are used any time you're using the parent PayPal class within the library.
 * 
 * We're using shorthand if/else statements here to set both Sandbox and Production values.
 * Your sandbox values go on the left and your live values go on the right.
 * 
 * You may obtain these credentials by logging into the following with your PayPal account: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run
 */
$api_username = $sandbox ? 'mohsin_api1.balianti.com' : 'LIVE_API_USERNAME';
$api_password = $sandbox ? 'DAQQ3QK5LTHHWGYV' : 'LIVE_API_PASSWORD';
$api_signature = $sandbox ? 'Ad9JZLf8.13dlHmFgFft2NVbaPK4AvTXPIYEMvf.CyBXiGxnrmbQG4l2' : 'LIVE_API_SIGNATURE';

/*
 * Payflow Gateway API Credentials
 * ------------------------------
 * These are the credentials you use for your PayPal Manager:  http://manager.paypal.com
 * These are used when you're working with the PayFlow child class.
 * 
 * We're using shorthand if/else statements here to set both Sandbox and Production values.
 * Your sandbox values go on the left and your live values go on the right.
 * 
 * You may use the same credentials you use to login to your PayPal Manager, 
 * or you may create API specific credentials from within your PayPal Manager account.
 */
$payflow_username = $sandbox ? 'SANDBOX_PAYFLOW_USERNAME' : 'LIVE_PAYFLOW_USERNAME';
$payflow_password = $sandbox ? 'SANDBOX_PAYFLOW_PASSWORD' : 'LIVE_PAYFLOW_PASSWORD';
$payflow_vendor = $sandbox ? 'SANDBOX_PAYFLOW_VENDOR' : 'LIVE_PAYFLOW_VENDOR';
$payflow_partner = $sandbox ? 'SANDBOX_PAYFLOW_PARTNER' : 'LIVE_PAYFLOW_PARTNER';

/* 
 * PayPal REST API Credentials
 * ---------------------------
 * These are the API credentials used for the PayPal REST API.
 * These are used any time you're working with the REST API child class.
 * 
 * You may obtain these credentials from within your account at http://developer.paypal.com
 */
$rest_client_id = $sandbox ? 'AUjqAhB6ZWMudj58C_NAC0kA58EmNCl2LPFlmaX76t1e0kVu-GwALjzVTBwR' : 'LIVE_CLIENT_ID';
$rest_client_secret = $sandbox ? 'EPXlgBAIfaptG15JI7OxxZK1GNxgfAqQg5uhmllzdF1FIE5hjEhsIBbrwfbV' : 'LIVE_SECRET_ID';

/* 
 * PayPal Finance Portal API
 * -------------------------
 * These are credentials used for obtaining a PublisherID used in Bill Me Later Banner code.
 * As of now, these are specialized API's and you must obtain credentials directly from a PayPal rep.
 */
$finance_access_key = $sandbox ? 'SANDBOX_ACCESS_KEY' : 'LIVE_ACCESS_KEY';
$finance_client_secret = $sandbox ? 'SANDBOX_CLIENT_SECRET' : 'LIVE_CLIENT_SECRET';

/**
 * Third Party User Values
 * These can be setup here or within each caller directly when setting up the PayPal object.
 */
$api_subject = '';  // If making calls on behalf a third party, their PayPal email address or account ID goes here.
$device_id = '';
$device_ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

My PHP Code i get from angel's eye paypal class:

```
<?php
// Include required library files.
require_once('config.php');
require_once('paypal.class.php');
require_once('paypal.adaptive.class.php');

// Create PayPal object.
$PayPalConfig = array(
                      'Sandbox' => $sandbox,
                      'DeveloperAccountEmail' => $developer_account_email,
                      'ApplicationID' => $application_id,
                      'DeviceID' => $device_id,
                      'IPAddress' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                      'APIUsername' => $api_username,
                      'APIPassword' => $api_password,
                      'APISignature' => $api_signature,
                      'APISubject' => $api_subject
                    );

$PayPal = new PayPal_Adaptive($PayPalConfig);

// Prepare request arrays
$PayRequestFields = array(
                        'ActionType' => 'PAY',                              // Required.  Whether the request pays the receiver or whether the request is set up to create a payment request, but not fulfill the payment until the ExecutePayment is called.  Values are:  PAY, CREATE, PAY_PRIMARY
                        'CancelURL' => $domain.'cancel.php',                                    // Required.  The URL to which the sender's browser is redirected if the sender cancels the approval for the payment after logging in to paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                        'CurrencyCode' => 'USD',                                // Required.  3 character currency code.
                        'FeesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER',                                  // The payer of the fees.  Values are:  SENDER, PRIMARYRECEIVER, EACHRECEIVER, SECONDARYONLY
                        'IPNNotificationURL' => '',                         // The URL to which you want all IPN messages for this payment to be sent.  1024 char max.
                        'Memo' => '',                                       // A note associated with the payment (text, not HTML).  1000 char max
                        'Pin' => '',                                        // The sener's personal id number, which was specified when the sender signed up for the preapproval
                        'PreapprovalKey' => '',                             // The key associated with a preapproval for this payment.  The preapproval is required if this is a preapproved payment.  
                        'ReturnURL' => $domain.'return.php',                                    // Required.  The URL to which the sener's browser is redirected after approvaing a payment on paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                        'ReverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => '',          // Whether to reverse paralel payments if an error occurs with a payment.  Values are:  TRUE, FALSE
                        'SenderEmail' => '',                                // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                        'TrackingID' => ''                                  // Unique ID that you specify to track the payment.  127 char max.
                        );

$ClientDetailsFields = array(
                        'CustomerID' => '',                                 // Your ID for the sender  127 char max.
                        'CustomerType' => '',                               // Your ID of the type of customer.  127 char max.
                        'GeoLocation' => '',                                // Sender's geographic location
                        'Model' => '',                                      // A sub-identification of the application.  127 char max.
                        'PartnerName' => 'Always Give Back'                                 // Your organization's name or ID
                        );

$FundingTypes = array('ECHECK', 'BALANCE', 'CREDITCARD');

$Receivers = array();
$Receiver = array(
                'Amount' => '10.00',                                            // Required.  Amount to be paid to the receiver.
                'Email' => 'mohsin@balianti.com',                                               // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                'InvoiceID' => '',                                          // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                'PaymentType' => 'GOODS',                                       // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                'Primary' => 'TRUE'                                             // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are boolean:  TRUE, FALSE
                );
array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

$Receiver = array(
                'Amount' => '5.00',                                             // Required.  Amount to be paid to the receiver.
                'Email' => 'mmskit@outlook.com',                                                // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                'InvoiceID' => '',                                          // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                'PaymentType' => 'GOODS',                                       // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                'Primary' => 'false'                                                // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are boolean:  TRUE, FALSE
                );
array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

$SenderIdentifierFields = array(
                                'UseCredentials' => ''                      // If TRUE, use credentials to identify the sender.  Default is false.
                                );

$AccountIdentifierFields = array(
                                'Email' => '',                              // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                                'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => '')                               // Sender's phone number.  Numbers only.
                                );

$PayPalRequestData = array(
                    'PayRequestFields' => $PayRequestFields, 
                    'ClientDetailsFields' => $ClientDetailsFields, 
                    'FundingTypes' => $FundingTypes, 
                    'Receivers' => $Receivers, 
                    'SenderIdentifierFields' => $SenderIdentifierFields, 
                    'AccountIdentifierFields' => $AccountIdentifierFields
                    ); 

// Pass data into class for processing with PayPal and load the response array into $PayPalResult
$PayPalResult = $PayPal->Pay($PayPalRequestData);



if(!$this->paypal_adaptive->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['Ack']))
    {
        $errors = array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['Errors']);

        // Write the contents of the response array to the screen for demo purposes.
        echo '<pre />';
        print_r($errors);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {

        header('Location: '.$PayPalResult['RedirectURL']);
        $ExecutePaymentFields = array(
                            'PayKey' => $PayPalResult['PayKey'],                                
                            'FundingPlanID' => ''                           
                            );

        $PayPalRequestData = array('ExecutePaymentFields' => $ExecutePaymentFields);

        $PayPalResult = $PayPal->ExecutePayment($PayPalRequestData);

        if(!$PayPalResult)
            {
        $errors = array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['Errors']);
        echo '<pre />';
        print_r($errors);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {

        echo '<pre />';
        print_r($PayPalResult);
    }   
 }

 if($PayPal->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['Ack']))
{
    // Redirect to PayPal so user can complete payment.
    header('Location: '.$PayPalResult['RedirectURL']);
}
else
{
    // Error    
    echo '<pre />';
    print_r($PayPalResult['Errors']);
    exit();
}
?>
```

my login information and whole detailed level information i received from paypal.

REST API CREDENTIALS

Test credentials

Your test credentials are enabled for all features in your app.

```
Test account:
mohsin-facilitator@balianti.com
Endpoint:  api.sandbox.paypal.com 
Client ID: AUjqAhB6ZWMudj58C_NAC0kA58EmNCl2LPFlmaX76t1e0kVu-GwALjzVTBwR 
Secret:    EPXlgBAIfaptG15JI7OxxZK1GNxgfAqQg5uhmllzdF1FIE5hjEhsIBbrwfbV
```

Here is your API signature:

```
API Username: mohsin_api1.balianti.com
API Password: DAQQ3QK5LTHHWGYV
Signature: Ad9JZLf8.13dlHmFgFft2NVbaPK4AvTXPIYEMvf.CyBXiGxnrmbQG4l2
```

Copy and paste the PayPal settings above into the API/Integration section of your Magento Configuration page.

You have successfully saved your preferences. Please use the following identity token when setting up Payment Data Transfer on your website. 
A9XxF-vXyH3-kPYVX0dDDcojmBxvMidXnmn846gxQD0ehzXM4Xjva0VL6RW

```
http://developer.paypal.com
mohsin@balianti.com
m@h$!nBali
```

please please help me resolving the whole issue. i am waiting for serious replies please.

Thank You All.

Comment: @Andrew K. Angell please help......

Comment: Have you run Pay.php by itself yet to ensure you're getting valid response with PayKey back from PayPal?

Comment: I have tried running the file it self but i have not get any response from the paypal.

Comment: please for god sake please my deadline is late already due to this problem please edit my code and make some working code that best helps me. i am using your library.

Comment: please for some sake help me out from this issue as i am very new to adeptive paypal.

Comment: i simply want when i press button lightbox appears and payment window comes that upon sender login split the money in two receivers. all should done in lightbox.

Comment: @AndrewAngell please help me out. my email is: mohsin@balianti.com. if  i am not available please please send me an email. i am badly stuck and losing my client trust due to this issue.

Comment: I'm looking at it now.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and ran it on my server here.

The first thing I notice is that you have everything commented out below the $PayPalResult getting loaded, so you didn't have anything actually happening with that result.  No output to screen or back to the requesting client.

When I run it with my credentials and look at the actual result, this is what I'm getting.

```
[Errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Receiver] => 
                [Category] => Application
                [Domain] => PLATFORM
                [ErrorID] => 520009
                [ExceptionID] => 
                [Message] => Account mohsin@balianti.com is restricted
                [Parameter] => mohsin@balianti.com
                [Severity] => Error
                [Subdomain] => Application
            )

    )

[Ack] => Failure
[Build] => 10273932
[CorrelationID] => 471e9fbfa0053
[Timestamp] => 2014-03-29T09:45:56.631-07:00
```

So it seems that there is something wrong with the receiver account you're using on this.  When I look into that more I see that you've got the same receiver set as both a primary and a secondary receiver on this same payment.

Once I replaced your receiver email address with 2 separate emails from my own sandbox accounts, I got a successful response.

```
[Ack] => Success
[Build] => 10273932
[CorrelationID] => 9afd1342ebf17
[Timestamp] => 2014-03-29T09:50:00.472-07:00
[PayKey] => AP-8FY50816521434738
[PaymentExecStatus] => CREATED
```

So then I went back and tried your account as a receiver along with one of my accounts, but I wound up with the same error about the account being restricted.

So, I'm not sure why that account would be restricted, especially on the sandbox.  It doesn't look like a sandbox email account, though.  Is it one?  You need to make sure you're using sandbox accounts when testing on the sandbox.

If you're actually hitting the live server and getting the same error then you'll need to [contact PayPal](http://www.paypal.com/mts) for help with what's wrong with that account.

You may be getting a different error, though, if you're running live.  To check that you need to look at the actual result that is coming back to $PayPalResult.  Again, you've got all of that commented out in your code, so it wouldn't even be returning a result back to your client request.

Comment: Dear Sir, i have created 2 new accounts in my sandbox account and they are still giving the same errors in the lightbox.

Comment: can you please write an optmized code for me? please that can give me results in lightbox and distrubute the money in 2 receivers that is one site admin means shopping cart admin and other is someelse receiver.

Comment: i am gonna edit my whole code you. please refer to my sandbox crediational as well. i am posting my whole form and crediationals now. please Sir optimized the code for me.

Comment: my mohsin@balianti.com is sandbox account with type business. so its business account. what i want is that main site admin who have a business account receive 10% and other receiver receive 90% and monies goes to both accounts at the same time. i want all this in light box so send login in lightbox and payment went through and site admin got 10% and other receiver receive 90%. please edit my whole code in this way. please.

Comment: My Dear Andrew Sir, please read my whole question again. and thank you very much for you great help. i have shared whole information with you now. please get me out of this problem. my client is really losing leads now. please.

Comment: I can't just do this work for you without billing you for time.  I also can't do anything about that you're getting, unfortunately. As I mentioned, that is something you'll need to [contact PayPal](http://www.paypal.com/mts) about.  The sooner you post something the quicker you'll get an answer back from them.

Comment: hey andrew. can you please explain this error?                          Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 520003
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

)

Comment: That error is pretty straight forward.  Need to double check your credentials, and also make sure you're not sending sandbox credentials to the live server or vice-versa.

Comment: please see my answer for the response

Answer (score 0):

please see.:

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 580022
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => Invalid request parameter: payKey cannot be null
                    [Parameter] => payKey
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

    [Ack] => Failure
    [Build] => 10273932
    [CorrelationID] => 2d63bc22401c7
    [Timestamp] => 2014-04-15T02:27:08.040-07:00
    [PaymentExecStatus] => 
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_US
    [XMLResponse] => 2014-04-15T02:27:08.040-07:00Failure2d63bc22401c710273932580022PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationInvalid request parameter: payKey cannot be nullpayKeynull
)
odftetretArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Receiver] => 
            [Category] => Application
            [Domain] => PLATFORM
            [ErrorID] => 580022
            [ExceptionID] => 
            [Message] => Invalid request parameter: payKey cannot be null
            [Parameter] => payKey
            [Severity] => Error
            [Subdomain] => Application
        )

)
```

Comment: The credentials won't show up here because they get sent in the headers as opposed to in the API request when you're working with Adaptive Payments.  You just need to double check your values and that you're posting to the correct endpoint.

Comment: thank you dear Sir. let me check please. i am using your classes but not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: [Contact me directly](http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) and I can help you more.

Comment: Dear Sir i have sent you the email please.

Comment: if you asks me for all the files i can share my all files with you and so emailed you in attachment on furthur requests.